# Emacs 24.4 in OS X 10.10 is not restoring windows configuration (desktop)

Tags: osx, desktop

I read that Emacs 24.4 should restore the desktop by default. It works perfectly except that the window configuration is not retained. It is saved because I can clearly read it in the desktop file, but when it starts up there is only one window in full screen. The others are loaded in their buffers but they are not displayed.

Comment: Does this happen with emacs -Q?

Comment: -Q appears to prevent emacs from loading the desktop file all together. So no luck.

Comment: But I just discovered that if I launch the GUI it restore windows correctly.

Comment: How do you load the package?

Comment: Are you trying to load a desktop in GUI emacs saved by a non GUI emacs or vice versa? I have encountered problems with this and there are known issues when doing so.

Comment: @JordonBiondo no, non gui to non gui

Comment: Do you get an error? I am seeing a similar problem but I get `Error (frameset): Wrong type argument: number-or-marker-p, nil` when loading the desktop.

Comment: Exactly that one

Comment: That information should be in your question, sounds like a bug. Use --debug-init and toggle-debug-on-entry to get a backtrace for the error. That information would also be helpful for people viewing your question. I can reproduce this with no other customizations. You should consider using M-x `report-emacs-bug` to send the error to the developers.

Comment: @gurghet, just encountered the same problem, also on OS X (and a newer version of Emacs 24.5.1). Did you resolve the problem in the end?

Comment: nope but i foubd the source of the problem

Comment: @gurghet, so what's the cause? If it is a Emacs bug, have you reported it?

Answer (score 1):

The reason that Emacs behaves differently when it is launched from the GUI than it is when launched from a shell, very likely is that these are actually different versions of Emacs. Apple ships an ancient version of Emacs with OS X and correctly places it on `$PATH`.

Unfortunately most of the third-party Emacs packages for OS X *don't* place the executable on `$PATH` so you have to do that yourself, e.g. in `~/.bashrc` if you use bash.

Comment: v24.4 as said in the title.